# Angular 2 configuration issues with Azure Slot deployments

Tags: angular, azure-web-app-service, azure-deployment-slots

I'm having a problem with Angular environment variables and Azure Slots

We want to use an app service providing static Angular files and we also want to use Azure slots to make our deployments safer.

The reasons we want to use slots are:

1. Ensure that code works in the production environment before making it fully available to everyone
2. Reduce downtime to almost nil as there is no build being deployed during the "go-live" phase

Our Angular site only serving up static files means that slot deployments require a different build to populate the env.json environment settings differently for each slot.

The solution we're thinking of taking is to create an endpoint in the same Angular website and make a call from the Angular site back to its origin to get its configuration. This way configuration can be set differently in the staging and production slots in Azure and only one Angular build would be required.

We need some server side code to pick up these Azure Application settings and provide them back in an endpoint on the site.  We are yet to make a decision about the technology we use to create that endpoint - we are thinking either .Net Core or NodeJs at the moment because they seem to fit well with the Angular product and the development team.

Does anyone have any experience of plugging in a server side component to provide configuration for a previously static Angular website?

Comment: This is a similar question to http://stackoverflow.com/q/42634154/7677661

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To achieve your requirement, you can just put the following PHP file to your site root folder. Then send a GET request to endpoint `http://<websitename>.azurewebsites.net/appSettings.php` via your Angular app. This will give you a JSON Object that contains all **App settings**.

***appSettings.php***

```
<?php

$appSettings = [];

foreach ($_SERVER as $key => $value) {

    if(preg_match('/^APPSETTING_/', $key)) {
        $appSettings[str_replace('APPSETTING_', '', $key)] = $value;
    }
}

header('Content-Type: application/json');
echo json_encode($appSettings);
```

Comment: Thank you very much!  By the way there is a missing end tag in the above example (?>).

Comment: From the [PHP Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/language.basic-syntax.phptags.php): "*It is preferable to omit the PHP closing tag at the end of the file, if If a file is pure PHP code*". By the way if my post was helpful, please accept it as the answer :)

Comment: Sorry I'm not an expert in the php language and I assumed it was a mistake.  I have accepted the answer, but due to my low reputation at the moment some things aren't quite working.  When I get enough I will definitely give it an uptick as well

Answer (score 1):

Maybe somebody still need it. I propose to stay closer to chosen technology and expose node.js api similar to previous php answer.

I create endpoint `http://<websitename>.azurewebsites.net/app-settings` exposed in Azure AppService as following:

Add index.js file into src directory in your Angular code:

```
var http = require('http');
var server = http.createServer(function (request, response) {
    response.writeHead(200, { "Content-Type": "application/json" });
    var result = {};
    result.someAppSetting = process.env.SomeApplicationSetting;
    var jsonResult = JSON.stringify(result);
    response.end(jsonResult);
});
var port = process.env.PORT || 1337;
server.listen(port);
console.log("Server exposing api for reading application settings running at http://localhost:%d", port);
```

So, response contains json with `SomeApplicationSetting` app setting retrieved from env vars by `process.env.SomeApplicationSetting`. Of course you can have other strategy of exposing variables like adding only some prefixed settings to json or any other.

Add index.js to assets in angular.json:

```
"assets": [
  "src/favicon.ico",
  "src/assets",
  "src/web.config",
  "src/index.js"
],
```

Then in web.config add following rewrite rule:

```
<rule name="Read app settings" stopProcessing="true">
  <match url="app-settings" />
  <action type="Rewrite" url="index.js"/>
</rule>
```

Comment: Hey @szalafe do you have some more info on how to actually deploy this to Azure? I'm not able to replicate this setup... also is there maybe a small repo on github as starting point ( could be I did something wrong of course ).

Answer (score 0):

I review all the solutions and I created one which are working on the Azure and the local machine also (localhost). It depends to build - `prod`(reads from azure) or `dev`(reads from local asset folder) the azure slots.

Maybe it helps to somebody.

First you need to add this small php file like `Aaron Chen` mentioned.
In the Angular structure under `src` folder:

**src/appSettings.php**

```
$appSettings = [];

foreach ($_SERVER as $key => $value) {

    if(preg_match('/^APPSETTING_/', $key)) {
        $appSettings[str_replace('APPSETTING_', '', $key)] = $value;
    }
}

header('Content-Type: application/json');
echo json_encode($appSettings, JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES | JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);
```

Need to modify the `angular.json` file. You need to add to `assets` the `"src/appSettings.php"`

```
        "assets": [
          "src/favicon.ico",
          "src/assets",
          "src/appSettings.php"
        ],
```

This solution gets all the configuration from azure in the `http://<websitename>.azurewebsites.net/appSettings.php` link.
This is working only in the Azure (need authentication). For the local development you need to create a Json file witch are contains all the Azure slots under the `src/assets` folder.

```
`assets/config/backend.json`;
```

To load the configurations Json need to create

**src/app/app.config.ts**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient, HttpBackend  } from '@angular/common/http';
import { AppSettings } from './models/AppSettings.model';
import { environment } from 'src/environments/environment';

@Injectable()
export class AppConfig {
    static appSettings: AppSettings;

    private http: HttpClient;
    constructor( handler: HttpBackend) {
        this.http = new HttpClient(handler);
    }

    public load() {
        let backendConfigUrl: string;
        if (environment.production) {
            backendConfigUrl = window.location.origin + '/appsettings.php';
        } else {
            backendConfigUrl = `assets/config/backend.json`;
        }
        console.log(backendConfigUrl);

        return new Promise<void>((resolve, reject) => {
            this.http.get<AppSettings>(backendConfigUrl).toPromise().then((response: AppSettings) => {
                AppConfig.appSettings = response;
                resolve();
            }).catch((response: any) => {
               reject(`Could not load file ${backendConfigUrl}: ${JSON.stringify(response)}`);
            });
        });
    }
}
```

Then modify the `src/app/app.module.ts` to load the configuration before the application starts.

```
export function initializeApp(appConfig: AppConfig) {
  return () => appConfig.load().then(() => {
    console.log(AppConfig.appSettings)
  });
}

 providers: [
    AppConfig,
    {
      provide: APP_INITIALIZER,
      useFactory: initializeApp,
      deps: [AppConfig],
      multi: true
    },
  ]
```

To `ng build` loads the config from the local `assets` folder. To `ng build --prod` reads the config from Azure. Is the same to `ng serve` and `ng serve --prod`

Comment: No matter what I try, the php file is just 'served' as text and not returning JSON. Is there anything special for config on Azure Web App to get this working? So Angular site with a running PHP?