# Azure Aplications Settings with Angular 6

Tags: angular, azure, deployment, visual-studio-code, azure-web-app-service

I m making a WebApp with Angular6 in vscode, this app will be deployed in Azure AppService with VSTS builds, so far so good.

But now i need to place some Aplications Settings in the AppService in Azure, and get Access to it at the start of the aplication. but i cant get the settings. there is some examples that use php, but i think there must be a better way.

I follow this tutorial:

[Azure Config Tutorial](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/premier_developer/2018/03/01/angular-how-to-editable-config-files/)

But i cant get filled the appsettings.json with the Settings.

Comment: did you find a good solution?
I'm looking into a solution where the typical ng environment setting are retrieved from the application settings in azure app service or via an azure key vault.

Comment: for now the only way i get it work is like in this post
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42693319/angular-2-configuration-issues-with-azure-slot-deployments/42712187#42712187